# How can PHP test if a given URL returns a 403 error

Tags: php

How can I test whether a given URL is a 403 error?

```
define('HTTP_STATUS', 403);
echo var_dump(http_response_code("badURL.com"));
```

and

```
 var_dump(http_response_code("bad_url.com"));
```

have not worked for me

Comment: Considering [the docs](http://php.net/http-response-code) clearly state that this function takes an *int*, what did you expect would happen when you gave it a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http_response_code` is for setting or retrieving the response status sent back to the client invoking your PHP script, it is not for making requests out to other services located somewhere on the Internet.

You can use `file_get_contents` to make a request to another service, then use `$http_response_header` to get the headers (including the HTTP response code).

```
function get_response_code($url) {
    @file_get_contents($url);
    list($version, $status, $text) = explode(' ', $http_response_header[0], 3);

    return $status;
}

var_dump(get_response_code('http://badurl.com'));
```

This will also support all forms of URLs that `file_get_contents` support, including `HTTPS` (if compiled with SSL support).

If you want to perform a ´HEAD` request instead, to avoid having to potentially download any content (.. but which may have its own issues, where it might not return the same error code), you can either use cURL or a custom HTTP verb with file_get_contents:

```
file_get_contents($url,
    false, 
    stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD' 
        )
    )
);
```

Or using cURL instead:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

// if you want to issue a HEAD request instead, uncomment the following
// updated from Havenard's comment - you might also want to set
// CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false if you don't want to verify SSL certificates.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

return status;
```

Comment: Considering `file_get_contents` will throw a massive error message for any 4xx or 5xx status code, this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @mario file_get_contents sets a magic variable, named `$http_response_header` that contains all the headers from the previous call to file_get_contents. @niet: Wrap it with @, then.

Comment: Now consider the case where the target is a forty bajillion megabyte file. What then? You going to wait for it to download all that just so you can get metadata?

Comment: @niet Well, that's an issue with several sides; either you can make a regular HTTP request and retrieve the header, or you can make a HEAD request, which may be denied or not handled properly on the other side. There are services that deny HEAD requests, while allowing GET to go through. There are upsides and downsides to both approaches. Implementing HTTP by yourself is not the solution. Use CURL or a custom verb with file_get_contents in that case.

Comment: Keep in mind cURL will by default dump all received data to the default output (send to user). You have to set some options. Also, you don't have to use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to set the method to `HEAD`, there is a proper option to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cURL:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://badurl.com/');
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_NOBODY         => true, // use HEAD method, no body data
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
));
curl_exec($curl);
$code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: I get a syntax error. ` unexpected '['` Do you know what that could be?

Comment: nevermind. you had a small syntax error. I corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: @thomas It was no error. Your PHP version must be outdated.

Comment: you can use square brace syntax with an array along with `=>` and commas? I'm sorry I did not know that. If that's more modern should I change it back? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[Not like that, certainly.](http://php.net/http-response-code)

Try actually getting it:

```
$fp = fsockopen("badURL.com",80,$errno,$errstr,1); // 1 second timeout to prevent lag
if( !$fp) echo "Failed to connect! ".$errno." ".$errstr;
else {
    fputs($fp,"HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: badURL.com\r\n\r\n");
    $line = fgets($fp); // get first line
    fclose($fp); // not interested in the rest
    list($version,$status,$statusText) = explode(" ",$line,3);
    var_dump($status);
}
```

Comment: This will test for a bad host, not a bad URL.

Comment: @Havenard You can just shove any request path/query string you want in the `HEAD / HTTP/1.0` part, you know...

Comment: @fiskfisk do you consider this or your solution to be better/faster? Thanks both!